# Self-adjunt operator is unbounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis

$H$ Hilbert space, $A\colon D(A)\subset H \rightarrow H$ an linear operator s.t. $A^*=A$ and $M\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\sigma{(A)}\subset [M,+\infty)$ implies $A\geq M$.

Comment: **Hint:** $\sigma(A - MI) = \{\lambda - M: \lambda \in \sigma(A)\}$

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this question. It's a good problem. And I have given a valid solution. $A$ here is allowed to be an unbounded selfadjoint operator.

Answer (score 1):

For $\epsilon > 0$, $B=(A-(M-\epsilon)I)^{-1}$ is bounded and selfadjoint with spectrum contained in the closure of the image of $[M-(M-\epsilon),\infty)=[\epsilon,\infty)$ under $1/z$, which is $[0,1/\epsilon]$. So,
$$
            \sigma\left((A-(M-\epsilon)I)^{-1}-\frac{1}{2\epsilon}I\right)\subseteq[-\frac{1}{2\epsilon},\frac{1}{2\epsilon}]
$$
Because norm and spectral radius are the same for bounded selfadjoint operators, and because $\sup_{\|x\|=1}|\langle Bx,x\rangle|=\|B\|$ for a bounded selfadjoint operator, then
$$
           -\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\langle x,x\rangle \le \langle(A-(M-\epsilon)I)^{-1})x-\frac{1}{2\epsilon}x,x\rangle \le \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\langle x,x\rangle.
$$
Only the first half the inequality is needed:
$$
          0 \le \langle (A-(M-\epsilon)I)^{-1}x,x\rangle.
$$
Now set $x=(A-(M-\epsilon)I)y$ for arbitrary $y\in\mathcal{D}(A)$ in order to prove
$$
           0 \le \langle y,(A-(M-\epsilon)I)y\rangle,\;\;\; y\in\mathcal{D}(A).
$$
Because this holds for all $\epsilon > 0$, and because $\langle Ay,y\rangle=\langle y,Ay\rangle$, then
$$
               0 \le \langle y,(A-M)y\rangle \\
               M\langle y,y\rangle \le \langle Ay,y\rangle,\;\;\; y\in\mathcal{D}(A).
$$